# Can a Custom URL in a Community be accessed when https:// is typed in?

Tags: community, custom-url

I have 3 communities in the following format:

```
ifsa.force.com/community1
ifsa.force.com/community2
ifsa.force.com/community3
```

I also have 2 of these sites set up with Custom URLs like this:

```
community1.company.com
community2.company.com
```

If no protocol (https or http) is prepended when visiting the communities via a custom URL, then everything works. If `http://` is prepended (making the URL `http://community1.company.com`) then everything still works. But when someone visits `https://community1.company.com`, we get the standard salesforce under construction page, with the message "`https://community1.company.com/community1` is under construction". Is this a custom URL issue or am I doing something wrong? I can't seem to find any documentation or answers on this.

A few notes:

1. HTTPS is required for all of our sites/communities.
2. The path for all of our communities is /community1, etc.
3. The custom URLs redirect to the exact same path as the community. community1.company.com resolves to /community1.

You can see this in action, the first two show the correct behavior and the last one is the problem:

- [students.ifsa-butler.org](http://students.ifsa-butler.org)
- http://students.ifsa-butler.org
- https://students.ifsa-butler.org

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce supports HTTPS but you must specify that on your [pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_security.htm)

When you do that, the URL would be as follows:

```
ifsa.secure.force.com/community1
ifsa.secure.force.com/community2
ifsa.secure.force.com/community3
```

That would then support the HTTPS variations as well.